# Docker run with ENV parameter pointing to a file in a mounted directory

Tags: windows, docker

I am building a docker image for an web application. For starting the application it requires a certifcate file. Since this certificate is specific to a particular developer, it cannot be part of the docker image but has to be passed to it when starting a container of this image.

So my plan was to

1. Mount my host directory containing the certificate in the container using the `--mount` option
2. Set an ENV variable containing the container path to the certificate which is consumed by the application

So like this:

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source=d:\\secret-data:/secret-data --envPATH_TO_CERT=/secret-data/my-cert thewebapp
```

This does not work,  the webapp throws an exception telling that it could not find the certificate in folder

```
c:/Users/myname/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/secret-data/my-cert
```

which is 1) a windows path which 2) indeed does not exist.

On the other hand, the mounting seems to work (when I connect to docker via `-it sh`, I can verify that there is a directory `/secret-data` containing the certificate `my-cert`

Comment: That’s an odd error; can you share more of the relevant code and Docker infrastructure?  IMHO it’s okay to hard-code this path in the image and document that you must `docker run -v somewhere:/secret-data` (and save a configuration step).

Comment: I am running docker Version 2.0.0.0-win78 (28905) on a Windows 10 system. The application I am trying to run in the container is a spring web application in a tomcat. So the image is derived from `tomcat:8.5.34-jre11` , the start command is `CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works to set the environment variable of the keystore path in the Dockerfile already. In my case I added it to the `CATALINA_OPTS` like this

```
ENV CATALINA_OPTS="-D/secret-data/my-cert"
```

The mount is done on startup of the container like before.

SiHa's correctly stated that this is not a workaround but the prefered way doing it ;-)

Comment: This looks less like a workaround than your original attempt, TBH. One might almost say it's the correct way to do it!